# How to do cherry-pick my commits to another git repository?

Tags: git, github

I create a new branch then add the other repository as a remote, then fetch its changes.

```
git fetch irep
git rebase irep/D29788
```

Then I do my local commits. 
How to add this commits to this branch `irep/D29788`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to do the following:

1) git log (found a commits that you want to cherry-pick, for example `123`)

2)`git checkout irep/D29788`

3) git cherry-pick `123`